# [Quartz]How to display scheduled Job?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, quartz-scheduler

I use Quartz with JobJDBCStore and it works perfectly. The problem now is that I want to display Job that will fire ,their dates of execution and some info that I put in the associated JobDataMap. 
Thanks you for your help

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with:

```
Scheduler scheduler = SchedulerSingleton.instance();
Trigger trigger = scheduler.getTrigger(job, group);
trigger.getNextFireTime()
```